# Capture internal ports

Tags: linux, wireshark

Is there any way to capture packets all through internal ports

for ex: 
A packets from 192.168.2.79 4000 to 192.168.2.79 4001

In this case its a TCP connection and the packets will not flow out of the box 
pls tell me is there any way to capture those packets

Comment: I tried with tcpdump with -i lo option and I could capture the localhost packets , but actually I did port forwarding using iptables command and I couldnt find those packets

Comment: you can use `wireshark` to capture and inspect all packets.

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You should read this: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback (try for example the part with the route sending all localip to the defautl gateway (and read the warnings))